# Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults value for key imgAssetURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, nsuserdefaults

```
__block NSArray *arrayImgAssetURL = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"imgAssetURL"];

    // if img url is not available then find image url and save to user default and
    if (!arrayImgAssetURL) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            arrayImgAssetURL = [[GALAssetsLibrary sharedReference] readImagesFromGallery];
            // write asset image url to user default
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [userDefaults setObject:arrayImgAssetURL
                             forKey:@"imgAssetURL"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];
        });
    }
```

Above method is crashed at [userDefaults setObject:arrayImgAssetURL forKey:@"imgAssetURL"];

Method [[GALAssetsLibrary sharedReference] readImagesFromGallery]; return the __block NSArray object, and it is assigned to arrayImgAssetURL which has values. Only when I'm trying to insert into userDefault it is crashed. NSUserDefaults only allow to insert  (array, data, string, number, date, dictionary). Then why it is going crash? and what is the solution of this?

Crash log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: 
attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=E3DCD905-082D-4D0C-886E-55CDFC669D41&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F471F275-AD0A-489F-9330-CB8A51571087&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=7F313D5B-CA0E-493C-9A1E-AC15BABFC741&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2270D5A3-0741-4278-9021-79FA89AAB6CB&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=239747B8-0586-490E-BCF1-6BB5675D47EE&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=882487BA-1A54-4B97-8B56-DB5409AB6262&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=88CDC266-CE00-44AB-A24B-9630B27E2AED&ext=JPG",
    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=3B6B3C09-9839-48C2-91EA-B26691445892&ext=JPG"
) for key imgAssetURL'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f21e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015718e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017f1fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x011a4a40 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 150
    4   FaceDetection                       0x0000296d __59-[MCAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]_block_invoke + 237
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x01e377b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x01e4c4d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x01e3aeb7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 291
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x01e3b127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x021772e3 _pthread_wqthread + 801
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x02174eea start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: what is the type of objects in arrayImgAssetURL? NSURL or NSString?

Comment: compare the arrayImgAssetURL isKindOfClass NSArray

Comment: Thanks kap, arrayImgAssetURL has NSURL object, when I convert it to NSString it works fine. Thanks :)